# SQLAlchemy query to return the date of the highest result

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I hope someone can help me with this. I am querying my db to find the object with the highest number of "F1". But then I want to return the date when it happened. Cannot figure out how to construct the second query...
My code:

```
Object1 = Class(end_time = "2016-12-01T08:00:00+0000", F1 = 10)
Object2 = Class(end_time = "2016-12-02T08:00:00+0000", F1 = 20)
session.add_all([Object1, Object2])
session.commit()

#return the instance with the highest F1
F1_query = session.query(Class.F1).order_by(Class.F1.desc()).first()
peak_date = ????
print("The highest number of F1 was " + str(F1_query[0]) + " on..." + str(peak_date))
```

Comment: How did you define the model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
f1, peak_date = session.query(Class.F1, Class.end_time).order_by(Class.F1.desc()).first()
print("The highest number of F1 was " + str(f1) + " on..." + str(peak_date))
```